# SET() or Please suggest suitable design

Tags: mysql, database-design, set

I guess this question is quite basic, but imo those are the hardest.

So lets say I want to create a table about the personnel details of person , and lets say other than basic info like name,address,contactno. etc. I also need to store whether the person is Investor,Mentor,HR Guy,ALumni,Partner,Donor or service provider. He can be in more than 1 fields listed above.

Is it recommendable to use the set() field with the 7 options? seems the logic way to do it but I've read that set() fields are not friendly with searches in big databases.

The other options I had in mind are:

1.Having 7 extra boolean columns for each field in the original table.

Which would be the best way, considering the database/table would be big?.

Plz suggest some good way out!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Normalize.

One table to hold the different types, then, since a person can be zero or more number of type, another table to glue them together. Consider a design something like this;

```
person:
--------------
id int
name varchar
email varchar
...


type
--------------
id int
name varchar


person_type
--------------
person_id
type_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hank . But are you sure this wont affect the searching speed as i will need to search mostly on basis of type_id...and it would take too much time to gain the basic info about person as it would intake joining..

Comment: both type.person_id and type.type_id should be primary keys and also join against primary keys, this is somewhat what a database does, and they do it really well.